# How to get POSIX timezone format from system timezone?

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I got lost on trying to convert windows timezone into POSIX standard format string like this one:

```
 TZ=CST6CDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00
```

I thought that Windows should has internal function to get this posix format.
Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You might check if NodaTime has that support, http://NodaTime.org. Otherwise, you will have to the conversion yourself.

Comment: Thank you..! This saving my time to create own conversion.

Comment: If you solved it, then you might post the answer and accept it.

Comment: POSIX format is highly unreliable, as it can only represent one set of transition rules.  See [the timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate to *why* you want to do this?  We may be able to suggest alternatives.

Comment: Buzz, what was the solution to this? Was it NodaTime?

Comment: NodaTime does not have the support. Is there any other tool suggested?